# Deep copy System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser Object/Restore State

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, browser, deep-copy

Essentially what I want to do is copy a WebBrowser object such that I can do the equivalent of "Open In New Tab" or "Open In New Window" actions, maintaining any posted data.  I don't just want to navigate to the same URL as in the original WebBrowser object, rather I want to repeat the HttpWebRequest.  Is this possible?  How?

Comment: For what it's worth, I tried inheriting from WebBrowser, marking the subclass as Serializable, and using serialization to make a clone, but the compiler still notifies me that System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser is not serializable.

Comment: Where are you trying to 'copy' the WebBrowser? The ViewState is deisgned to maintain page conditions across postbacks. You have two options for changing page at the server Server.Transfer and Response.Redirect. Not sure I understand the context in which you are trying to accomplish this.

Comment: I'm trying to copy the WebBrowser object in a VB.Net application, not ASP.Net.  The application is a webcrawler which, in some cases, uses a Forms.WebBrowser object for page navigations which involve javascript or form posts.  Unfortunately, the httprequest is not exposed in Microsoft's browser object, so I can't duplicate a form post request in a new browser, so I was hoping to replicate the state of a WebBrowser by other means.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the WebBrowser object is a control, and therefore it has a window handle, which is going to cause issues if you try to clone it. I don't think you're going to get the behavior you want doing this.