# Assigning a webbrowser control object to another webbrowser control

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, webbrowser-control

I have two webbrowser control in a windows Form Application. I have navigated to a page in webbrowser control1. Now i need to assign this webbrowser1 to webbrowser2 and i need to work in these two webbrowser controls differently.

But the result i tried,

```
webbrowser2 = webbrowser1;
```

When i did this and whatever i do in webbrowser2 will be affected in webbrowser1. Is it possible to assign a webbrowser object to other without affecting the first and continue working in second webbrowser control.

**Edit - My Workflow**

I'm doing (automation work) like login into a web account (ex. Gmail) and do certain actions after login successful. So at this point I have to copy the logged in webbrowser object to some other object to  continue doing some automation works without affecting the first one. If i copy just url to another browser i have to again  do the login automation work.

Comment: How about `webrowser2.Url = webbrowser1.Url;`

Comment: @rene  I'm doing (automation work) like login into a web account (ex. Gmail) and do certain actions after login successful. So at this point I have to copy the logged in webbrowser object to some other object to  continue doing some automation works without affecting the first one. If i copy just url to another browser i have to again  do the login automation work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write this code:

```
webbrowser2 = webbrowser1;
```

You are giving `webbrowser2` the reference to `webbrowser1`. This means they literally **point at the same object**. Because of this, you would expect that modifying one would affect the other.

So the basic answer to your question is: **No, you cannot assign one to the other and keep them independent.** The suggestion by @rene (assigning just the URL values) works if you just want them to display the same page (while remaining separate instances).

Depending on what you are trying to do, there are other approaches, but we would need more information to help with that.

Comment: I'm doing (automation work) like login into a web account (ex. Gmail) and do certain actions after login successful. So at this point I have to copy the logged in webbrowser object to some other object to  continue doing some automation works without affecting the first one. If i copy just url to another browser i have to again  do the login automation work.

Comment: @Narayan, I don't think you can do that (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794117/deep-copy-system-windows-forms-webbrowser-object-restore-state). Couldn't you just create a new web browser and re-login? You may need to re-work your requirements a bit.